# How to determine which files are behind origin/master in Git

Tags: git

When I run the command 'git status' on my work-area, I get the message show below:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

Now if I run the command 'git pull' the work-area is updated with the files that are ahead on the origin/master. The command also displays on the screen the files that are being pulled in to update my work-area.

Is there a way to determine this file list without actually running the 'git pull' command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--stat` flag of `git diff` against the remote branch.

```
git diff --stat origin/master
```

This will show the list of files that have changed along with how many lines were removed/added.  This also will not update your current branch's reference in any way.

Answer (score 4):

`git diff --stat master origin/master` would do the trick.

You can also shorten it to `git diff --stat HEAD @{u}` if origin/master is set as the upstream branch for master.

Answer (score 1):

To see what commits have been added to the upstream master, run a `git log` using `origin/master` as a filter. Will show the commits.

> `git fetch`
>   `git log --oneline master..origin/master`

**example output:**
    **2d8ad7d** fix a whole bunch of stuff
    **c1ee8ec** updated some values

Then use the `commit id` to view the files of a commit.

> `git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r`**`2d8ad7d`**
>   **or**
>   `git diff --stat -r`**`2d8ad7d`**

**Note:** This example and your solution is tracking the remote branch `origin/master`. If you are tracking a different branch, replace that branch name in the command above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command

```
git diff HEAD origin/your/feature/branch
```

Given you have checked out your feature branch locally and are seeing this message:

> Your branch is behind 'origin/your/feature/branch' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.

This shows the difference between your local state and the remote feature branch.

Answer (score -1):

Try `git fetch` and [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Comment: `git reflog` isn't going to give you a list of what's changed.  It's going to give you a list of SHAs and actions taken with respect to those SHAs.